# How to make a custom Animation play once

Tags: java, android, animation, android-studio

here is my animation class that i'm using to draw Objects in a SurfaceView :

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Animation {
private Bitmap[] frames;
private int currentFrame;
private long startTime;
private long delay;
private boolean playedOnce;

public void setFrames(Bitmap[] frames)
{
    this.frames = frames;
    currentFrame = 0;
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
}
public void setDelay(long d){delay = d;}
public void setFrame(int i){currentFrame= i;}

public void update()
{
    long elapsed = (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/1000000;

    if(elapsed>delay)
    {
        currentFrame++;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
    if(currentFrame == frames.length){
        currentFrame = 0;
        playedOnce = true;
    }
}
public Bitmap getImage(){
    return frames[currentFrame];
}
public int getFrame(){return currentFrame;}
public boolean playedOnce(){
    return playedOnce;
}
```

}
but!, `playedOnce` method isn't working!
the animation keeps looping..
am i missing something? how to fix this?

Comment: Ypu never check if played once is true (in which case i imagine you need to exit somehow)

Comment: What you exatly want??/

Comment: @DixitPanchal i want my frame animation to play one time

Comment: @Ethan You get back the value of playedOnce. But this variable not Intilized

Comment: @DixitPanchal So what should i do?!

Comment: @Ethan private boolean playedOnce=false; n try your activty

Comment: @Ethan Are you absolutely sure that `playedOnce` is ever being set to `true`? If you don't set a delay, you would never ever meet the conditions to do so.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev yes i'm sure, cuz i have a delay it's in my object class!